# Python framework to create pure backend project

Tags: python, django, pylons, web-frameworks

Some details about the project:

- pure backend project, no front
- expose a rest api (maybe custom routes?)
- connect to other rest apis
- query MySQL & MongoDB using an ORM
- have unit tests

What Python framework would you recomend me for it?

Comment: Why did you tagged your question with django and pylons but didn't include directly names of other python web-frameworks?

Comment: any of them your requirements aren't exactly unique.

Comment: @TomWillis Considering the fact that I don't need any interface/views, I can choose a 'lighter' framework (with less/no support for views/templates) ;)

Comment: then use a "lighter" one. it still stands that these aren't unique requirements. and thus any web framework will work based on your bullet points. this question simply provides an opportunity for everyone to list their favorite framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any of them will work.  Arguably the most popular Python web frameworks these days are Django, Flask, and Pyramid.

Comment: Appears Pylons and Zope2 are (still) more popular, if counting by number of pypi installs: https://python3wos.appspot.com.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider cherrypy ([cherrypy.org)](http://cherrypy.org/). From their website:

> CHERRYPY IS A PYTHONIC, OBJECT-ORIENTED WEB FRAMEWORK
>
> CherryPy allows
> developers to build web applications in much the same way they would
> build any other object-oriented Python program. This results in
> smaller source code developed in less time.

For more information on creating rest services in cherrypy, see [Creating RESTful applications in CherryPy](http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/progguide/REST.html?highlight=rest) in the cherrypy documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Bryan about Cherrypy also you can try Flask

http://flask.pocoo.org/

> Flask is a microframework for Python based on Werkzeug, Jinja 2 and
>   good intentions.

Answer (score 1):

[Django Piston](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home) may be the solution.

For MongoDB, you can find something in this [IBM blog](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-django-mongo/index.html) and in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424562/django-nonrel-vs-django-mongodb-vs-mongokit-vs-pymongo-native)