# Work with mongoDB and Django

Tags: django, mongodb

i'm asking a question. When working with mongoDB, can we return a django response with a document(get with find_one()) and work with or do i have to parse the document to build json  and return it ?

Comment: Could you please use mongo engine, please refer  http://mongoengine.org/

Comment: The question is too vague to answer. MongoDB is a database, and although it works in a different way to SQL databases the principles of using it in an application are pretty much the same. What, exactly, are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options here. If you want to have an abstraction layer (ORM), you should consider using:

- [mongoengine](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/index.html) ([docs](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/django.html) on django support)
- [django-mongodb-engine](http://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/)
- [other packages](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/mongodb/)

Alternatively, if you want be "closer to metal", you can just use [pymongo](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/) (python mongodb driver) directly. But, I bet you will quickly find yourself reinventing wheels.

Also see similar questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972480/has-anybody-actually-used-django-mongodb
- [Django-nonrel vs Django-mongodb vs Mongokit vs pymongo native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424562/django-nonrel-vs-django-mongodb-vs-mongokit-vs-pymongo-native)

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for the help, but can i combine 2 ORM. I currently use Mysql to stock several datas but i need to Mongo to store huge amount of datas. ex: mysql store datas related to a thermometer like name, position, etc. all datas collected are stored in mongo

Comment: I don't have that experience, but, I'm pretty sure you can. Don't hesistate to ask any specific question in a separate thread if you'll have any problems with it.